# Sqlite Error during inserting multiple values

Tags: python, sqlite

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqkJ9.jpg)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw4Y7.jpg)

When i try to run this python file , i see the below error on by git-bash terminal :

```
$ python database_insert_many.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\AutomationTesting\SQL_Database_Practise\SQlite3_Practice\database_insert_many.py", line 19, in <module>
    c.execute("INSERT INTO customers('first_name','last_name','email') VALUES (?,?,?)", str(many_customers))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 3, and there are 103 supplied.
```

Comment: Copy/Paste your code rather than upload a picture, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the error message is explicit. Your insert statement

```
"INSERT INTO customers('first_name','last_name','email') VALUES (?,?,?)"
```

contains 3 `?` and so expects 3 values. That means that the `execute` parameter should be a sequence of 3 values like `('John', 'Doe', 'John.Doe@example.com')`. Instead of that you are passing a single string (`str(many_customers)`) which happens to be 103 characters long.

Here you are trying to insert 3 tuples as the same time. That means that you should use `executemany`:

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO customers('first_name','last_name','email') VALUES (?,?,?)",
              many_customers)
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert multiple records in sqlite, you need to run a code similar to this

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

records = [(1, 'Glen', 8),
            (2, 'Elliot', 9),
            (3, 'Bob', 7)]

cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO students VALUES(?,?,?);',records)

conn.commit()
#close the connection
conn.close()
```

See [this](https://pythonexamples.org/python-sqlite3-insert-multiple-rows-to-table/) tutorial for more info

Comment: @samrac happy to help